# Facing issues in writing def inside if in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

This I need to do

```
def x1(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y):
    if Delta(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y) >= 0:
        return 2*(b(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y)**3) - 9*a*b(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y)*c(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y) + 27*(a**2)*d(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y)
    else:
        return None

def y1(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y):
    if Delta(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y) >= 0:
        return 3*np.sqrt(3)*a*np.sqrt(Delta(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y))
    else:
        return None
```

This is creating a problem, output:

```
return np.sqrt(x1(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y)**2+y1(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y)**2)
   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

so I want to write it like

```
def Delta(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y):
    Delta = 18*a*b(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y)*c(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y)*d(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y) - 4*(b(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y)**3)*d(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y) + (b(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y)**2)*(c(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y)**2) - 4*a*(c(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y)**3) - 27*(a**2)*(d(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y)**2)
    if Delta(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y) >= 0:
        def x1(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y):

            return 2*(b(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y)**3) - 9*a*b(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y)*c(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y) + 27*(a**2)*d(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y)
        def y1(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y):
            return 3*np.sqrt(3)*a*np.sqrt(Delta(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y))
    return x1, y1
```

but it is also making a definition error.
Actually by defining such functions i have to construct some new functions like U1(),U2(),U3() using the x1(),y1() and atlast I have to satisfy the best-fit values for U1(),U2(),U3() for this I am doing a for loop run of the variables ap,dp.... Etc. In range (-10,10) to find the all possible set of variables which satisfies the best fit

Comment: Where is `b` defined? Where is `a` defined? Your second example isn't going to work. `if Delta(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y)` isn't going to work since you have set `Delta` equal to number value by the looks of it. Don't try to overload methods, just fix the original problem.

Comment: In my original code a is defined to 1 and b() has a functional form.

Comment: Work on fixing your original problem by finding out what variable is None. Python is complaining saying that one of your variables or results is None, which of course you cannot run pow() operation on.

Comment: So basically it looks like if `x1` or `y1` returns `None` then you cannot run operation `**` on `None`. Instead, if you must run power operation on the result, return something that isn't going to break the application. Maybe return `0` ? Without know what you're trying to calculate I cannot say exactly what you can do. But you need to handle the `None` return appropriately.

Comment: I have to calculate some parameter points. For those the only acceptable solutions are for Delta>=0 so I want to skip the other possibilities i.e. Delta<0 values

Comment: Single letter variable and function names... no doc strings or comments... I'd hate to debug this code

Answer (score 1):

Your definition error appears to be due to improper indentation. You're returning x1 and y1 outside of the if statement where they're defined.

Your TypeError `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'NoneType' and 'int'` implies that either `x1(...)` or `y1(...)` returns `None`, which you allow in your function definition. I'd suggest changing that to explicitly throw an error, assuming `None` is not a desirable return value. Looking at your code, it seems that Delta(...) is negative when it shouldn't be.

```py
def x1(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y):
    "x1 is a function that does something"
    variables = [ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y]
    varnames = "ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y".split(',')
    keywordargs = {k:a for (k,a) in zip(varnames, variables)}

    a = 5 # keep `a` in local scope, or include it as a function argument 
    # e.g., along with ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y

    if Delta(**keywordargs) >= 0:
        return 2*(b(**keywordargs)**3) - 9*a*b(**keywordargs)*c(**keywordargs) + 27*(a**2)*d(**keywordargs)
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Delta should be non-negative, but instead was {Delta(**keywordargs)}")

def y1(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y):
    "y1 is a function that does something"
    variables = [ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y]
    varnames = "ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y".split(',')
    keywordargs = {k:a for (k,a) in zip(varnames, variables)}

    a = 5 # keep `a` in local scope, or include it as a function argument 

    if Delta(**keywordargs) >= 0:
        return 3*np.sqrt(3)*a*np.sqrt(Delta(**keywordargs))
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Delta should be non-negative, but instead was {Delta(**keywordargs)}")
```

And...

```py
def Delta(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y):
    "Delta does some crazy stuff"
    variables = [ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y]
    varnames = "ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y".split(',')
    keywordargs = {k:a for (k,a) in zip(varnames, variables)}

    a = 5 # keep `a` in local scope, or include it as a function argument 

    # Avoid defining variables with the same name as their function, to avoid confusion and accidental recursion...
    delta_val = 18*a*b(**keywordargs)*c(**keywordargs)*d(**keywordargs) \
                - 4*(b(**keywordargs)**3)*d(**keywordargs) \
                + (b(**keywordargs)**2)*(c(**keywordargs)**2) \
                - 4*a*(c(**keywordargs)**3) \
                - 27*(a**2)*(d(**keywordargs)**2)

    if delta_val >= 0:
        def x1(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y):
            return 2*(b(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y)**3) - 9*a*b(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y)*c(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y) + 27*(a**2)*d(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y)
        def y1(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y):
            return 3*np.sqrt(3)*a*np.sqrt(Delta(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y))
        return x1(**keywordargs), y1(**keywordargs)
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Delta should be non-negative, but instead was {delta_val}")
```

Also, what is `a`? I hope it's not a mutable global variable that gets changed throughout your application... because that will create hard to find bugs. I'd recommend avoiding having functions depend on variables that are defined outside of the function (or class containing the function) if you can.

Also, for the love of all that is sacred, make your function names longer or capitalized or something, to help distinguish them from all your one letter variable names. Also, consider having more descriptive variable names, or include comments. Code is read more than it is written. You don't want to make debugging harder than it has to be.

---

#### EDIT

After looking at your code a second time, it would be even better if you simplified things further and kept all your functions separate from each other.

```py
# Define your functions separately
def X1(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y,a,a):
    """X1 is a function that does something

    Input: ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y,a
    Output: some crazy number
    Dependencies: b(), c(), d()
    """
    variables = [ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y,a]
    varnames = "ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y,a".split(',')
    keywordargs = {k:a for (k,a) in zip(varnames, variables)}

    result = 2*(b(**keywordargs)**3) \
              - 9*a*b(**keywordargs)*c(**keywordargs) \
              + 27*(a**2)*d(**keywordargs)

    return result

def Y1(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y,a):
    """Y1 is a function that does something

    Input: ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y,a
    Output: some crazy number
    Dependencies: Delta(), b(), c(), d()
    """
    variables = [ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y,a]
    varnames = "ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y,a".split(',')
    keywordargs = {k:a for (k,a) in zip(varnames, variables)}

    if Delta(**keywordargs) >= 0:
        return 3*np.sqrt(3)*a*np.sqrt(Delta(**keywordargs))
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"Delta should be non-negative, but instead was {Delta(**keywordargs)}")


def Delta(ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y,a):
    """Delta does some crazy stuff

    Input: ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y,a
    Output: some crazy number
    Dependencies: b(), c(), d()
    """
    variables = [ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y,a]
    varnames = "ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y,a".split(',')
    keywordargs = {k:a for (k,a) in zip(varnames, variables)}

    # Avoid defining variables with the same name as their function, to avoid confusion and accidental recursion...
    delta_val = 18*a*b(**keywordargs)*c(**keywordargs)*d(**keywordargs) \
                - 4*(b(**keywordargs)**3)*d(**keywordargs) \
                + (b(**keywordargs)**2)*(c(**keywordargs)**2) \
                - 4*a*(c(**keywordargs)**3) \
                - 27*(a**2)*(d(**keywordargs)**2)

    return delta_val

# Run your already defined functions
if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    # ... give values to ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y,a

    variables = [ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y,a]
    varnames = "ap,dp,ph,e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,y,a".split(',')
    keywordargs = {k:a for (k,a) in zip(varnames, variables)}

    if Delta(**keywordargs) >= 0:
        x1,y1 = X1(**keywordargs), Y1(**keywordargs)
```

Basically, you want to keep the logic of your program separate from individual function definitions. Build your program up from smaller, simpler functions that don't depend on outside global variables or functions.

Also capitalize B(),C(),D(), or give them different names. Do something to show that they're functions and not variables.

Comment: Note if you want the function to work when delta is less than 0, I'd recommend having it return 0 and print a warning. That way 0**some_number will still work

Comment: @ Andre Ricardo This is ok with return 0 but inside my code there is some (y1/x1) form also which will then causing a ZeroDivisionError, I need to skip such values

Comment: In that case, don't make functions `X1()` and `Y1()` depend on `Delta()`. Define them all separately, and then only call `X1` and `Y1` when `Delta(**keywordargs) >= 0`. (Note that this is also very different from defining functions whenever `Delta(**keywordargs) >= 0`).

Comment: thanks for clearing some of my doubts but I  have now  explained my problem with more words

Comment: Yeah I still have no idea what you're trying to do. What is this for?

Comment: U1(),U2() s are some well measured values and for those i have the free parameters ap,bp,....I need to know the parameter points which satisfies the U1(),U2() best fit bounds. So I have used for loop. There will be lot of those parameter points

Comment: It sounds like you have a different problem now. I can't really tell. If my answer answered your original question as to why you were getting definition errors and NoneType TypeErrors, feel free to mark it as accepted.